# AVPLayer - Convert linear volume control to logarithmic

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, avplayer, avaudioplayer

I've implemented an incremental volume control for my AVPlayer player that uses 0-1 values in 0.1 steps. I want to convert that to logarithmic +/- instead. It's written in Objective-c / COCOA - NOT SWIFT.

Here is my incremental AVPlayer volume control:

```
// TRANSPORT CONTROLS
- (void) keyUp: (NSEvent *) event {
    if(event.keyCode == 53) { // ESC
        if([self isInFullScreenMode]) {
            [self toggleFullscreen];
        } else {
            [self.window close];
        }
    } else if(event.keyCode == 36) { // ENTER
        [self toggleFullscreen];
    } else if(event.keyCode == 49) { // SPACE
        if (player.rate != 0 && player.error == nil) {
            [player pause];
        } else {
            [player play];
        }
        

// AUDIO CONTROLS
    // MUTE
    } else if(event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 113) { // M
        if(player.volume == 0) {
            player.volume = 0.8;
        } else {
            player.volume = 0;
        }
// VOLUME UP
    } else if(event.keyCode == 116) { // PageUp
        {
            if(player.volume < 1) {
            player.volume = (player.volume += 0.1);
        }
        else {
            player.volume = 1;
        }
    }
// VOLUME DOWN
    } else if(event.keyCode == 121) { // PageDown
        {
            if(player.volume > 0) {
            player.volume = (player.volume -= 0.1);
            }
            else {
            player.volume = 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is a code snippet that adds an "extension" to AVPlayer but I don't know how to make this work in my code. Are these "extension" resources that need to be added to the project or just properties of standard AVplayer?

```
extension AVPlayer {    
var logarithmicVolume: Float {
        get {return sqrt(volume)} set {volume = pow(newValue, 2)}
}}
```

I believe it's in the value type being incompatible - I think it needs to be converted on the fly from float to int(between 0-1)? Unsure but your assistance is appreciated.